# BBEdit regex replace only works when using "Replace All"

Tags: regex, bbedit

Looking to replace all examples like this:

`"1%"`

`"10%"`

with:

`"1.0%"`

`"10.0%"`

Here is my regex:

`"(\d+)%"`

And here is my replace pattern:

`"\1\.0%"`

If I click "Replace" I get this error:

**The replacement string couldn’t be computed, because the previous Grep search did not succeed (application error code: 12003).**
The replacement string couldn’t be computed, because the previous Grep search did not succeed (application error code: 12003).

However, if I click "Replace All," it works.

I'm guessing this is *my* error, as this is a very basic task. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I contacted BBEdit's support and they guessed I was stuck in "Find All" mode and that wouldn't let me grep through the individual matches. By clicking "Find" I broke out of that mode and it worked to do one at a time. Silly answer but I guess that's it...

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex as: (\d+)%

And replace pattern as: $1.0%

Here is demo: https://regex101.com/r/E3M4k5/1

or

You can try regex as: (\d+)

And replace pattern as: $0.0

Here is demo: https://regex101.com/r/nM2rAq/1

Comment: Hi @hitesh. 1. It seems the capture group is referred to as `\1` in BBEdit, not `$1`. 2. I need the quotes around it to match the pattern (there are lots of other values in the code that I don't want to match). That said, even after changing your `$1` to `\1` and adding the quotes in, I'm still faced with the same issue—it only works when using "Replace All"!